# Using Python to get a table from a website

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to get the data from a table or object from this website. I am new to this and I have been stuck for over a week. I would like to be able to save it as and excel file or a text file. this is the website with the data I would like to get. My code said there is no table.  Thanks for any help. "https://www.swf-wc.usace.army.mil/cgi-bin/rcshtml.pl?day1=05&month1=08&year1=22&Submit1=Submit&page=Reports&report=morn&csrf=cbptbpFggR"

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import  openpyxl

url = 'https://www.swf-wc.usace.army.mil/cgi-bin/rcshtml.pl?day1=01&month1=01&year1=18&Submit1=Submit&page=Reports&report=morn&csrf=cbptbpFggR'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[0]
print(df)
df.to_excel('C:\\Users\\jeffr\\Desktop\\code\\swf1.xlsx')
```

Comment: It's not actually an HTML table. It's just a pre-formatted text block.

Comment: Use `View Source` with the web site and you'll see it.

Comment: Actually there's no html table on the page, it's rendered as plain text using a `pre` tag, so instead you can get the text and then process this text using for example regex expressions

Comment: You also need headers. Otherwise you get a 403. 
`headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)`

Comment: I think javacript is also involved. Check out https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/ `response.status_code
response.text`